# UI testing using Selenium in .NET

Tags: .net, selenium, automated-tests

I'm a .NET developer, and I am thinking of automating my UI testing since it is taking quite a lot of my time to test my UI. I'm thinking of using Selenium, but according to this website http://seleniumdotnet.blogspot.com/ i should be using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate or Premium to use selenium in .NET. Now, we are currently using VS 2010 Professional in our office, and I'm just wondering if there's some workaround to this, so that we could use selenium while not upgrading our Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is just an IDE, Selenium .NET binding is supposed to be working on any version of VS 2010.

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate has more features to help you developing .NET, but without it, Selenium library will still work fine, as it only depends on .NET framework, not IDE.

That post is misleading, you can totally use VS 2010 Professional for everything described in that. Moreover, you can choose more commonly used open-source [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) instead VS Unit Testing Framework. That post basically shows one way of doing things, not the only way, may not be the best way.

For more information, please refer to the **Official Documentation**, [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) or [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare) is the comparison of different versions of VS, none of the features matter Selenium. Unless, you have some special needs for your .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any specific version of VS to use Selenium in your project. You can also use Selenium toolkit from http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com to use it in your project. You can use any testing framework to use Selenium in your project. You can use NUnit, MSTest etc. based on your liking.

Recently Visual Studio has come up with new Coded UI test (CUIT) test manager which helps you write those test cases easily. Using that tool, it helps you create the UI test cases without writing any code as the code would be auto generated which can be edited though. But to use this tool, you need to have VS premium or Ultimate.

You can learn more about that tool from msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx.

Besides Selenium, you can also use Watin watin.org for the same task.